# Ring of invariants of symmetric group acting on ring of formal power series

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-polynomials, formal-power-series, regular-rings

Let $k$ be a field and $R=k[[x_1, \dots, x_n]]$ be the ring of formal power series in $n$ variables. Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group of order $n!$. Then $S_n$ acts on $R$ by $k$-automorphisms by permuting the coordinates. Let $R^{S_n}$ be the subring of $R$ of all elements that are fixed by the action of $S_n$. How can I prove that $R^{S_n}$ is regular, i.e., that it has Krull dimension $n$? The author claims that this follows from the fact that any symmetric polynomial in $A[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ over any ring $A$ can be expressed in a polynomial equation in $\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_n$, where $\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_n$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials. I don’t see how the statement follows from this fact.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials also gives uniqueness of that representation that exists. So, you have the isomorphism $k[[x_1,...,x_n]]\to R^{S_n}$ given by $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\mapsto f(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,...,\sigma_n)$.

Comment: Thanks. How do I show, that the map is well-defined? Do I have to show that the l-adic topology on $R^{S_n}$ for $I=(\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_n)$ is complete? Also, the fundamental theorem on symmetric polynomials says that the map $k[x_1, \dots, x_n] \to k[x_1, \dots, x_n]^{S_n}$, defined by $x_i\mapsto \sigma_1$ is an isomorphism. How does this extend to power series?

Comment: We are substituting variables. So, being well defined is not a problem. You only get one result. Being defined is because we are composing with elements of the ideal $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$. While the theorem is written for polynomials, note that for each $n$, the terms of total degree $n$ forms a symmetric polynomial. So, we apply the theorem for each degree. That is how we know that the map is surjective.

Comment: @owl How do I see rigorously that the above map is a ring-homomorphism? How can we apply the theorem for each degree, I don't see how that works in detail.

Comment: Checking that you can compose power series with other power series as long as the latter are in the ideal $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ is simple, but tedious. It is just a matter of checking that only finitely many of the coefficients are involved in computing each coefficient of the result. After all composing $x^a$ with $\sigma$ will have total degree $\geq a$, if $\sigma\in(x)$. So, none of the terms of $\sigma^a$ contribute to terms of smaller degree.

Comment: For the homomorphism part, just any composition yields one, since $(fg)\circ\sigma=(f\circ \sigma)(g\circ\sigma)$ and $(f+g)\circ\sigma=f\circ\sigma+g\circ\sigma$.

Comment: The part that you work degree by degree is to prove that it is onto. Let $F\in k[x]^{S_n}$ and $F_k$ be the polynomial formed by collecting the terms of $F$ that have total degree $k$. Observe that $F_k\in k[x]^{S_n}$. Therefore, by the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials, there is a unique $f_k$ such that $f_k\circ\sigma=F_k$. Let $f=\sum_k f_k$. Here you do need to check that for each degree $n$ the $f_k$ for large $k$ eventually stop contributing terms of degree $n$. That tells you that $f\in k[[x]]$ and that is your pre-image of $F$.

Comment: I believe in the last comment you meant $F\in k[[x_1,  \dots, x_n]]^{S_n}$, $F_k\in k[x_1, \dots, x_n]^{S_n}$ and $f \in k[[x_1, \dots, x_n]]$. Thank you for your help, know I think I can work the details out by myself.